# How write compareTo method for Generic class with 2 parameterized types using Comparable Interface

Tags: java

My code is as follows

```
class Students<I ,S > implements Comparable<Students<I,S>>{
    private I age;
    private S name;
    public Students(I a, S n){
        age = a;
        name = n;
    }
    public int compareTo(Students<I,S> s){
        if(age > s.age){return 1;}
        else if (age <s.age){return -1;}
        else{return 0;}
    }
    public I getAge(){return age;}
    public S getName(){return name;}
    public String toString(){
        return " "+name;
    }
}
```

While executing I'm getting
java: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
first type:  I
second type: I

How to compare age which is Integer object for which I'm unable to access age.intValue() also,
Please let me know.

I tried to sort custom class object, while class is a generic class which has 2 type. I need to sort based on Integer class variable

Comment: Why do you need the age and name to be generic? Aren't they simply going to be something like... int and String?

Comment: The error you're receiving is because it does not know what type _age_ or _s.age_ is.  Cast those values to _int_ or _Integer_.

Comment: @Reilas That's probably not good advice.

Comment: @shmosel, _probably not_?  What does that mean?

Comment: @Reilas It's very likely that either `I` is unneeded and casting can be avoided, or `I` is needed and casting will fail.

Comment: @shmosel, oh, okay.  Thanks.  You should iterate what you're complaining about, in an answer.

Comment: @Reilas it's not appropriate for an answer because it's not responding to anything asked by OP in the question: it's responding to your comment. (And shmosel is correct: don't cast something when you can instead declare the field as having that type).

Comment: @AndyTurner, that's great.  _"... unable to access age.intValue() also"_.  Typically you would require an identity to access the method.  In Java this is called _casting_ a value.

Comment: @Reilas if you make the field of type `Integer` (or `Number` more generally), you can access the `intValue()` method without casting. Selecting the correct type for a field is a far better choice than casting, because it avoids the possibility that the cast isn't allowed at runtime. Making it `int` instead of `Integer` is even better again, because it also avoids the possibility of a NPE.

Comment: @AndyTurner, the question is, _"How [to] write compareTo method for Generic class ..."_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it currently is, you can't do it, since `I` and `S` now are `Object`s. You need to either:

1. Introduce bounds for your generic parameters:

```
class Students<I extends Comparable<I>, S extends Comparable<S>> implements Comparable<Students<I, S>> {
  private final I age;
  private final S name;

  public Students(I age, S name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Students<I, S> s) {
    int cmp = this.age.compareTo(s.age);
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }
    return this.name.compareTo(s.name);
  }
}
```

Like this `I` and `S` can be only types that implement `Comparable` and you can use their `compareTo()` methods.

2. Or you can depend on [Comparators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to make the comparison for you.

```
class Students<I, S> implements Comparable<Students<I, S>> {

  private final I age;
  private final S name;
  private final Comparator<I> ageComparator;
  private final Comparator<S> nameComparator;

  public Students(I age, S name, Comparator<I> ageComparator, Comparator<S> nameComparator) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.ageComparator = ageComparator;
    this.nameComparator = nameComparator;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Students<I, S> s) {
    int cmp = ageComparator.compare(this.age, s.age);
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }
    return nameComparator.compare(this.name, s.name);
  }
}
```

**Warning**: The second option is not really recommended, as it may break a general requirement of `Comparable` - `The implementor must ensure signum(x.compareTo(y)) == -signum(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.` I would only use it as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks @Chaosfire For the Comparator approach as well, But those comparators only works for built in class objects, For Custom Class object we need to create Comparator object with defined compare() method  in main n  pass it to constructor I think so, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sumanthparamkusam Comparators work for any class, built-in or custom. They are used define ordering different from the natural ordering (Comparable), so most of the time you define them yourself, regardless of the class being custom or built-in.

Answer (score 0):

> How to compare age which is Integer object for which I'm unable to access age.intValue() also, Please let me know.

No, it's not. Because `age` is an `I`, it's an instance of that type variable (or null), which can be anything at all: an `Integer`, a `String`, an `Object`, a `List`, a `ClassThatIHaveJustWritten`...

If you need `age` to be an instance of `Integer`, declare it as one (or as an `int`, if you never expect it to be null), and you'll then have no trouble using `<` to compare it - although you'll find it easier just to use the `Integer.compareTo` (or `Integer.compare`) instead.

---

If you *really* need to compare things for a generic `I` (that is, not an `Integer`, contrary to what is stated in the question), you need to bound `I` so that it implements `Comparable` (as well as the `Students` class itself), which allows you to call the `compare` method on that:

```
class Students<I extends Comparable<? super I>,S > implements Comparable<Students<I,S>>{
    private I age;

    // ...
    public int compareTo(Students<I, S> s) {
      return age.compareTo(s.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of solutions, opposed to just to re-iterating the question?

Comment: @Reilas the second paragraph explains what to do instead.

Comment: Can you provide some solutions, some code, that will solve the question?

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner, I couldn't put my doubts entirely in the question, But you have exactly given queries to all my queries in shot. I need to understand about wildcards a little bit more to get clarity on <? super I> but I understand extends comparable<I> is required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class Students<I extends Comparable<I>, S> implements Comparable<Students<I, S>> {
    private I age;
    private S name;

    public Students(I a, S n) {
        age = a;
        name = n;
    }

    public int compareTo(Students<I, S> s) {
        return age.compareTo(s.age);
    }

    public I getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public S getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " " + name;
    }
}
```

To resolve this, you can add a type constraint to I to ensure it extends the Comparable interface. This way, you can use the compareTo method on I to compare the age values.
The code I've shared has the type parameter I is constrained to extend Comparable, indicating that it should be a type that supports comparison. Inside the compareTo method, you can directly call the compareTo method on the age objects to compare them.
Hope this will work in your case.

Comment: Thanks @adbul Mueed for Simple and Understandable Solution.

Answer (score -2):

To re-iterate the error you're encountering.

```
java: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
  first type:  I
  second type: I
```

The term *[binary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)* is a mathematical term—not to be confused with *[Bitwise operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)*, which typically provide functionality in terms of *[binary code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code)*.

A *binary operator* is simply a *[relational operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)*.

```
x > y
```

In your code you have two conditional statements which use the binary operator.

```java
if(age > s.age){return 1;}
else if (age <s.age){return -1;}
```

The reason for the error is because both *age* and *s.age* are of type *I*.
Which is defined, here

```java
private I age;
```

In order to identify type *I*, you can use a *[type cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html)*.

Since, you are passing in an *integer* value, you can use the *int* type cast.

```java
if((int) age > (int) s.age){return 1;}
else if ((int) age < (int) s.age){return -1;}
```

As a note, if you're using an *Integer* object for *I*, you can utilize the *[auto-boxing and un-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)* feature.
This will convert your *Integer* to an *int* primitive, or, alternately, your *int* primitive to an *Integer*.

So, this is a simple way of typing the following.

```java
if(((Integer) age).intValue() > ((Integer) s.age).intValue()){return 1;}
else if (((Integer) age).intValue() < ((Integer) s.age).intValue()){return -1;}
```

A few notes on your code.

Your *[generic-type variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)* can be any upper-case letter, *A* through *Z*.

Since you are comparing an integer value, you can utilize the *[Integer#compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer))* method.
Here is the source code for *[Integer#compareTo](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L1465)* and *[Integer#compare](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L1483)*.

Keep in mind here that you'll need to cast the value to an *Integer*, and not a *int*.
Auto-boxing will not take a precedence during the method invocation.

```java
public int compareTo(Students<I, S> s) {
    return ((Integer) age).compareTo((Integer) s.age);
}
```

Finally, here is a great tutorial on *Java Generics*.
*[Lesson: Generics (Updated) (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)*.

Comment: This is not a good approach. By adding static casts, you are introducing the possibility of runtime failure (by ClassCastException, specifically), if `Students` is instantiated with an `age` that is not an `Integer` (something that is not forbidden by the current declaration). Generics allow you to omit some casts which will be inserted by the compiler; if you are using generics and explicitly casting, you are often doing something wrong.

Comment: @AndyTurner, the question states, _"How to compare age which is Integer object for which I'm unable to access age.intValue() also ..."_.

Comment: Thanks @Reilas for all the Basic's detail you mentioned, Those are really helpful for beginners Like us in understanding each and every line in Errors as well as Code..!!

Comment: @sumanthparamkusam, no problem, glad it helped.  My additional recommendation would be to try and reduce the generic-type _I_.  For example, if you think you may need a number that is either a _Double_ or an _Integer_ you can use an `<I extends Number, S>`.  This would allow the compiler to differentiate the type, more accurately.  Furthermore, I find utilizing the primitive data-types whenever possible is helpful; the _wrapper classes_ should be used whenever you feel the encapsulation is required, which in this case, it most likely is.